# How to cite a complex web-based resource?

Tags: citations, online-resource, citation-style

I want to cite the [IUPAC Compendium of of Chemical Terminology - Gold Book](http://goldbook.iupac.org/) in ACS reference style (American Chemical Society). This resource is not just a web page and the ACS reference guide doesn't provide a style for this kind of web resource. On the other hand, the IUPAC Gold book provides a citation style under "Cite as" on individual pages.

What should I do? Cite as is given under "Cite as" or cite it as a single web page?

Comment: Do you use the resource solely as a web page, and not as a PDF/printed document? If so, then it _is_ just a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a resource tells you how it wants to be cited, cite it that way.